# How do I evaluate this sum for $s$ is a complex variable :$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2s}n!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-theory, dirichlet-series

This question related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1575992/230303) question in SE ,I would like to know how do I

evaluate this sum for $s$ is a complex variable :$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2s}n!}$$ .

**Edit01**:And I think the General  complex solution of $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{2s}n!}=0$$ would be $s=-1+i\beta$ for some values of $\beta$ and for $\beta =0$ it's a trivial zero

**Note 01** :In wolfram alpha the series is converge but i don't know if it has a nice closed form and really the convergence in complex number ensemble is not clear !!!

**Note 02** I edited the question only for the zeros of this series since it's convergent after some computation in wolfram alpha!!!

Thank you for any help

Comment: Even the case $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{1/2}n!} \approx 0.725065152077915927$$ seems to have no known closed form.

Comment: but how  do i show that is hasn't  no closed form , is by mathematica ?

Comment: Note for instance that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n\cdot n!} = \int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}dx$, which has no known closed form expression.

Comment: @RichardStanley: we may consider the exponential integral function $\mathrm{Ei}(x)$ to be "closed form".  But the square-root case doesn't even have that.

Comment: Hint for convergence with complex $s$: investigate absolute convergence.

Comment: I meant $\int_0^1 \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}dx$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar,do you meant that the series absolutely converge for all s \in  \mathbb{c} ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mathematica* says that 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^k n!} = 
\, _kF_k(1,\dotsc, 1;2,\dotsc,2;-1),$$ where the numbers of $1$s (and $2$s) are both equal to $k.$ This suggests to me that there is no closed form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , do you meant no general form of solution existed and what it does meant F_k ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I believe there is no closed form, and the notation means hypergeometric pFq (where $p=q=k,$ in this case).

Comment: @ Igor Rivin, This Series converge for all s , is it true ?

Comment: @zeraouliarafik check out Gerald Edgar's comments...

Comment: , The question has been answered here in S.E http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1924182/230303